# Blurry, distored, unreadable snap apps

Tags: 22.04, firefox, display, budgie, spotify

I've just run into issues with some of the applications on Ubuntu. The two that I've first noticed were Firefox and later Spotify. Tried uninstalling and reinstalling, no change. As the title says, both installed through the snap store. I honestly don't even know where to begin with this. I've searched online and haven't found anything that looks similar to this. I'm posting the two screenshots below.

```
Spotify version 1.2.8.923.g4f94bf0d  
Mozilla Firefox 111.0.1  
Distributor ID: Ubuntu  
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS  
Release:    22.04  
Codename:   jammy  
Budgie version 10.6.1
Graqphics: AMD Radeon rx 5500 xt

lspci -v | grep VGA -A 1 ->  
2b:00.0 VGA compatible controller:   
Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 14 [Radeon RX 5500/5500M / Pro 5500M] (rev c5) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])    
Subsystem: XFX Pine Group Inc. Navi 14 [Radeon RX 5500/5500M / Pro 5500M]

sudo lshw -C video ->  
       description: VGA compatible controller  
       product: Navi 14 [Radeon RX 5500/5500M / Pro 5500M]  
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]  
       physical id: 0  
       bus info: pci@0000:2b:00.0  
       logical name: /dev/fb0  
       version: c5  
       width: 64 bits  
       clock: 33MHz  
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master  
 cap_list rom fb  
       configuration: depth=32 driver=amdgpu latency=0 resolution=1920,1080  
       resources: irq:71 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e0000000-e01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fcb00000-fcb7ffff memory:c0000-dffff

glxinfo -B ->  
name of display: :0  
display: :0  screen: 0  
direct rendering: Yes  
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):  
    Vendor: AMD (0x1002)  
    Device: AMD Radeon RX 5500 XT (navi14, LLVM 15.0.6, DRM 3.42, 5.15.0-69-generic) (0x7340)  
    Version: 22.2.5  
    Accelerated: yes  
    Video memory: 8192MB  
    Unified memory: no  
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)  
    Max core profile version: 4.6  
    Max compat profile version: 4.6  
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1  
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2  
Memory info (GL_ATI_meminfo):  
    VBO free memory - total: 7136 MB, largest block: 7136 MB  
    VBO free aux. memory - total: 8107 MB, largest block: 8107 MB  
    Texture free memory - total: 7136 MB, largest block: 7136 MB  
    Texture free aux. memory - total: 8107 MB, largest block: 8107 MB  
    Renderbuffer free memory - total: 7136 MB, largest block: 7136 MB  
    Renderbuffer free aux. memory - total: 8107 MB, largest block: 8107 MB  
Memory info (GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info):  
    Dedicated video memory: 8192 MB  
    Total available memory: 16368 MB  
    Currently available dedicated video memory: 7136 MB  
OpenGL vendor string: AMD  
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon RX 5500 XT (navi14, LLVM 15.0.6, DRM 3.42, 5.15.0-69-generic)  
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 22.2.5  
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60  
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)  
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile  

OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 22.2.5  
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60  
OpenGL context flags: (none)  
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile  

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 22.2.5  
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
```

I've tried to update this to include any graphics info as requested.

[spotify screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FI5Qv.png)

[firefox screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxlu1.png)

Comment: looks more like a graphics issue

Comment: A question about a graphical issue with no info on the graphics card or the driver being used does not offer any info to help with. Please use edit and add this critical info to the question. Please do not answer in a comment.

Comment: @David I tried to update the question will all of the information you requested, please let me know if there's more that would be helpful.

Comment: A workaround is to use the APT versions. For firefox, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22/1404401#1404401. You can get the debian installer of Spotify from https://www.spotify.com/us/download/linux/

Comment: This may contain useful information: [Hardware acceleration broken for amdgpu/mesa in snap](https://launchpad.net/bugs/2004532).

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem after upgrading from Ubuntu 22.10 to 23.04. Both Firefox and Spotify snaps would look like this:

[image: Broken Spotify on Ubuntu 23.04]

It seems to be a Wayland problem with non-Wayland snaps.

I could fix Firefox by forcing it to use its Wayland backend: you should add

```
export MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1
```

at the end of the file `.profile` at your Home.

I still haven't been able to fix Spotify. Will update if accomplished.

Comment: Do the apt packages of these apps have the same issue?

Comment: No they don't, I've just checked with Spotify.